# Parse string of paths into JSON object

Tags: python, json, graph, decision-tree

I have a bunch of strings (1) that represent a graph/decision tree (2). Each character represents a path along the graph.

```
###1###
'0A1B'
'0A1A'
'0A0A'
'0A0A'
'0B10'
'0B11'
```

[image]

I want to process this list of strings in Python to create a JSON variable with the following structure (3):

```
###3###
{
"name": "0",
"count": 6,
"children": [
    {
    "name": "A",
    "count": 4,
    "children": [
        {"name": "0",
        "count": 2,
        "children": [
            {"name": "A", "count": 2}
        ]
        },
        {"name": "1",
        "count": 2,
        "children": [
            {"name": "A", "count": 1},
            {"name": "B", "count": 1}
        ]
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "B",
    "count": 2,
    "children": [
        {"name": "1",
        "count": 2,
        "children": [
            {"name": "0", "count": 1},
            {"name": "1", "count": 1}
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Is there a library that can make this easier? 
I'm able to use the `json` library to create json objects, but not sure how to parse the string. It seems like a recursive function is necessary?

Comment: Where are you getting the weights ("count") from those strings? For example, why is the weight of `A` on the lower left `2`?

Comment: @Grismar The counts are the number of times that we 'took that path'. For example, the first path, `0`, is traversed `6` times because there are `6` strings and they all start with `0`. The weight for `A` on the lower left is `2` because there are two occurrences of '0A0A'.

Comment: "a recursive function is necessary?" Recursion is never necessary. Everything coded recursively can also be coded iteratively. And Python is much better in iterations.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How would you deal with a string that does not start with a `0`? The data structure you've chosen for the output only allows a single node at that level?

Comment: @Grismar The python code should add that node into the `json` output if there is a string that starts with a 1. So, for example, if we added a 7th string that started with a 1 the python code should now add that to the json var

Comment: You should probably add that to the example, because I think you'll find there's no unambiguous way to add it. The JSON dict cannot have two `"name"` entries (one for `"0"` and one for `"1"`, for example). This is caused by the odd structure of having `"children"` at every level, but not at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need any specific libraries, other than the built-in `json`:

```
import json


def dict_tree(ss):
    # there has to be at least one string and it has to have at least 1 character
    assert ss and ss[0]
    result = {'name': ss[0][0], 'count': 0}
    for s in ss:
        # all strings should start with the same character 
        # (the suggested data structure does not support more than one name at the root level)
        assert s and s[0] == result['name']
        p = result
        p['count'] += 1
        for ch in s[1:]:
            if 'children' not in p:
                p['children'] = []
            for child in p['children']:
                if child['name'] == ch:
                    p = child
                    break
            else:
                p['children'].append({'name': ch, 'count': 0})
                p = p['children'][-1]
            p['count'] += 1
    return result


def main():
    strings = [
        '0A1B',
        '0A1A',
        '0A0A',
        '0A0A',
        '0B10',
        '0B11'
    ]
    print(json.dumps(dict_tree(strings), indent=4))


main()
```